# HTML Quiz Returns Extra Marks

Tags: javascript, html

https://plnkr.co/edit/J1LqWB?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    div#test {
      border: #000 1px solid;
      padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var pos = 0,
      test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, pic, title, points, correct = 0;
    var questions = [
      ["Can you hear what he is ____________?", "saying", "speaking", "telling", "talking", "A", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["She hasn't come home ____________.", "still", "already", "yet", "till", "C", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["I ____________ TV yesterday evening.", "saw", "looked", "viewed", "watched", "D", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["We live ____________ the city centre.", "near", "next", "by", "nearby", "A", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["She looks ____________ a famous film star.", "as", "like", "similar", "different", "B", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["You must admit flying in a hot air balloon is an amazing ____________.", "expression", "experience", "expertise", "none of the above", "B", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["Can you remember the last time you ____________ such an exciting time?", "have", "having", "had", "none of the above", "C", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["To be honest, I have never ____________ in a balloon.", "flowed", "flown", "flying", "none of the above", "B", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["Really, then it's about time you tried it ____________.", "in", "out", "on", "none of the above", "B", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["Are you really suggesting that we ____________ actually get into one of those ridiculous things?", "shall", "will", "should", "none of the above", "C", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["Why not? There is nothing to be ____________ of. After all it won't be just us in the balloon.", "fear", "afraid", "fright", "none of the above", "B", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["You must be joking. Have you forgotten how terrible I felt the last time we went somewhere ____________ plane?", "in", "with", "by", "none of the above", "C", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["Oh, come on. Why do you have to be such a kill____________.", "joy", "joke", "fun", "none of the above", "A", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["That's not fair. You know full ____________ what it feels like to be worried sick when everyone else is laughing at you.", "good", "well", "fine", "none of the above", "B", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["All right you win. I promise I won't bring it ____________ again. Why don't we just go white water rafting instead?", "on", "up", "in", "none of the above", "B", "", "Part 1: Basic English", "1"],
      ["Clearly their father had been a wise man because all the work the sons had done on the land ensured that they had the best ____________ for years.", "gathering", "yielding", "crop", "production", "C", "", "Part 2: Structure", "1"]
    ];

    function _(x) {
      return document.getElementById(x);
    }

    function renderQuestion() {
      test = _("test");
      if (pos >= questions.length) {
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>Total Score: " + correct + "/50 </h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
      }
      _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;
      question = questions[pos][0];
      pic = questions[pos][6];
      chA = questions[pos][1];
      chB = questions[pos][2];
      chC = questions[pos][3];
      chD = questions[pos][4];
      title = questions[pos][7];
      test.innerHTML = "<h1>" + title + "</h1>";
      test.innerHTML += "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
      test.innerHTML += "<img src=" + pic + "><br>";
      test.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='choices' value='0'>";
      test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "<br>";
      test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "<br>";
      test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "<br>";
      test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " + chD + "<br><br>";
      test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
    }

    function checkAnswer() {
      choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
      for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        if (choices[i].checked) {
          choice = choices[i].value;
        }
      }
      if (choice == questions[pos][5]) {
        correct += Number(questions[pos][8]);
      }
      pos++;
      renderQuestion();
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="test_status"></h2>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

So I've been working on this online quiz and it works fine for the most part, except for a weird bug which I can't wrap my head around. It has to do with the scoring portion of the test. When I answer all questions, it works fine; when I answer no questions, it also works; but when I answer the first question for example, and proceed to press submit for the rest, it gives me a much higher mark for example 7 when I should get 1 mark.

I have tried adding a hidden choice output to set it to default, but it doesn't work. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "it gives me a much higher mark for example 7 when I should get 1 mark"

Comment: So at the end of the quiz, there is a score function. When I only answer the first question correctly, I expect 1 mark. However, I get 7 marks. This only happens if I answer a few questions but leave the rest blank.

Comment: Try after checking if the answer is right, deselecting the option

Comment: Thanks, but how do i do that exactly?

Comment: Ahh I found your fix. I will write it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset the choice before you get the current choice. This sounds strange but what keeps happening is that once the first choice is checked, the choice variable is set to whatever the user choose first. So even if the user doesn't choose anything later down the line, the choice variable is still set from before.

There are two ways to fix this. Set choice to null right after this line:  `choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");`

Or you can make the variable choice inside the checkAnswer function (I would do this) because we don't need it globally.

Comment: @GanZheJing feel free to mark it as a correct answer so people can see this in the future ;)